# how can i add computed field in res.partner related to sale order in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12, computed-field

I'm in `res.partner` model and I add this:

```
points = fields.Integer(string="Points", required=False, store=True, readonly=True, compute='_point_calc',
                        track_visibility='always', track_sequence=6)

@api.one
@api.depends('name')
def _point_calc(self):
    points = 0

    for part in self:
        orders = part.env['sale.order'].search([('partner_id', '=', part.id)])
        part.points = 0
        for order in orders:
            part.points += order.point_total
```

to get the point I calculate on each sale order the customer has been done 
but I get an error

```
return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'sale.order' - - -
```

Comment: What is `part.env`?

Comment: like self.env
put self return recordset not one record

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one record try:

```
orders = self.env['sale.order'].browse([('partner_ids', '=', part.id)])
```